# HIPAA compliance

Tags: 7

I'm building an application that needs to be HIPAA compliant. I've already gotten a HIPAA compliant server through Rackspace. I'm wondering whether I still need to use encryption/decryption modules such as these: http://drupal.org/project/aes and http://drupal.org/project/encrypt. How safe are these? I've looked into this company that encrypts your entire database: http://www.gazzang.com, but I don't see why I'd need to do that if I can just encrypt the necessary columns of my database. Can you guys shed some light on this

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing the [AES module](http://drupal.org/project/aes) [has a security flaw](http://drupal.org/node/1114780) that exposes the password on the 'My Account' page when JavaScript is disabled (read: not so HIPAA compliant). For that reason I would either not use it, or seriously consider fixing that issue and contributing a patch to the D.O. community ;)

Both modules encrypt a string of text that you pass to their functions, however, they do not handle the storage of the ciphertext. You would still be required to write a custom Drupal module that stores let's say the contents of a Drupal field into the database using the functions provided by these modules.

I would be seriously concerned about the performance characteristics of encrypting the entire database. e.g., I wouldn't use it without doing some performance benchmarks first.